# How do I access the AuthorizationProvider outside of .razor files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have an apsnet core application with razor components. I Use Discord OAuth for login and can read the claims in the .razor files.

```
@foreach (var c in context.User.Claims)
        {
            <li>@c.Type: @c.Value</li>
        }
```

How can I access these claims outside of the razor components?
I want to find user in my own database with an Id matching the discord Id from the login.

I found that I can make a component class that the razor component can inherit from and that the AuthenticationStateProvider contains the user / claims. But how do I get it or do I need something else?

TestComponent.cs:

```
public class TestComponent: ComponentBase
{
    public string SomeTestText { get; set; }
    private AuthenticationStateProvider asp{ get; set; }
    
    public TestComponent()
    {

        SomeTestText = "Hello World!";
        GetUser();
    }

    private async Task GetUser()
    {
        var authState = await asp.GetAuthenticationStateAsync(); // asp is null
        var user = authState.User;
        SomeTestText = user.Claims.First().Value;
    }
}
```

Test.razor:

```
@page "/test"
@inherits Models.TestComponent;

<h1>@SomeTestText</h1>
```

**EDIT**:

Just adding [Inject] didn't work for me; it is still null.

Since it is an ComponentBase and not a PageModel(?) I can't inject the ClaimsPrincipal in the constructor. I tested it also with [Inject] but it didn't work either.

Here is my Startup.cs for more context:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using SlpyGrdn.Database;
using SlpyWeb.OAuth.Discord;
using System;
using System.Security.Claims;


namespace SlpyWeb
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup( IConfiguration configuration )
        {
            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddConfiguration(configuration)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

        }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();

            services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
            {
                opt.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = DiscordEndPoints.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddDiscord(x =>
            {   
                x.AppId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DISCORD_APP_ID");
                x.AppSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DISCORD_APP_SECRET");
                x.SaveTokens = true;
            });
            services.AddDbContext<SlpyDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CONNECTION_STRING")));


            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddScoped(svc => svc.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext?.User ?? new ClaimsPrincipal());
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env )
        {
            if ( env.IsDevelopment() )
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides.ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I found a work-around:

```
@page "/test"

@inherits Models.TestComponent;

<h3>Test</h3>

<p>@SomeTestText</p>

@code { 


   [CascadingParameter] private AuthenticationStateProvider asp { get; set; }

   protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
   {

       var authState = await asp.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
       var user = authState.User;
       DoSomething(user);

       await base.OnInitializedAsync();
   }
}
```

"DoSomething" is a Method in TestComponent. So I just relay the Userclaims to my class. Not the best solution, but it'll work for now.

Comment: Funny using @inject works perfectly in my case. And this is the way to go according to Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=webassembly#request-a-service-in-a-component). Also, according to the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#authenticationstateprovider-service you can inject the state provider no need for cascading parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [inject] attribute to @inject classes registered with DI.

```
[Inject] private AuthenticationStateProvider asp {get; set;}
```

Comment: Try adding @attribute [Authorize] to the top of Test.razor

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with Discord OAuth implementation. But if I follow the razor component, the middleware will just use the HttpContext.User object to pass along the current identity. So instead of using the specific implementation I would rely on the .net provided supporting classes and only use the ClaimsPrincipal located at HttpContext.User

So before you can start accessing the user it needs to be registered in the DI container as this is not done by default.

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddScoped(svc => svc.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext?.User ?? new ClaimsPrincipal());
```

Then you can inject the ClaimsPrinciple in any component by adding

```
@inject ClaimsPrincipal User
```

If this needs to present in every razor component/view/page you can add the @inject statment in the _ViewImports.cshtml file. This shared view is added to all you razor vies.

Now if you need to access it outside your razor components just add a ClaimsPrincipal into your constructor like this.

```
public class OutsideRazorComponent 
{
    private readonly ClaimsPrincipal _user;

    public OutsideRazorComponent(ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        _user = user;
    }

}
```